# Migration from ASP.NET MVC to ASP.NET Web API

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-4, knockout.js, asp.net-web-api

I am an **ASP.NET MVC** developer since nearly two years. I am now working on a new project for my internship and I want to use **ASP.NET Web API** instead of classic ASP.NET MVC.

- Do I need an extra effort to become accustomed to ASP.NET WEB API and the way it works?
- Does the ASP.NET MVC fundamentals stay relevant in the case of Web API (like the membership providers, the role providers, the authentifiacation and authorization systems...) ?
- Can I use ASP.NET MVC inside of an ASP.NET Web API project ?

I will be very grateful if you give me some resources or tutoriels that are targeted to ASP.NET MVC developers who want to migrate to Web API using **Knockout JS** and may be some other **javascript libraries**. Any help or idea about the subject will be apreciated :) Thank you guys ! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) You could read something about REST, HTTP Methods, .NET Web API Implementation...
2) Yes, ASP.NET MVC fundamentals stay relevant in the case of Web API.
3) You could use ASP.NET Web API inside of an ASP.NET MVC 4 or 5 projects ;) You could create controllers, that inhereted from ApiController instead of Controller. All features, that you could use in Web API project, you also could use in MVC project.
You could use Knockout JS with Web API by the same way that with MVC. For learn Knockout you could go to http://knockoutjs.com/ and read Tutorial, Documentation and pass Live Examples. Also, http://www.knockmeout.net/ is a very good site about Knockout.

Comment: Thank you for your response ! Can you give some other resources about how to use Web API with KO, I must say that my javascript skills are a bit limited and that in the recent years I didn't concentrate on client side development. I must catch out now ;)

Comment: Knockout not depend on Web API, and Web API not depend on knockout :) Knockout is used for data presentation and manipulation on Client side.

Comment: And for get data from server, for post data to server and etc. you could use Web API Controllers on server side (inhereted from ApiController) and jQuery methods like a $.get, $.post, $.ajax on client side.

Comment: You could read about it in "Pro ASP.NET MVC 4 book by Adam Freeman and Steven Sanderson" or other books about MVC 4 or MVC 5. Also you could read about jQuery AJAX requests in this documentation https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/. jQuery is not required and you could use another library or poor JS, but I using jQuery and haven't any problems :)

Comment: Yes I saw some tutoriels that use basic Js, JQuery and Ko, but I am really impressed about how Ko establishes the data binding :) Many Thanks Ivan

Comment: For understand how data-binding and Knockout works you could start with http://learn.knockoutjs.com/. It is really good and interesting live-tutorial :)